# freezing in TimeSeriesForecast[]

Tags: time-series

I have been running TimeSeriesForecast[] over a large number of TimeSeriesModels, and finding that it freezes for some models for some datasets for reasons for reasons I can not figure out.

See the path I've put online at http://pastebin.com/L6Saif1q for one example.

```
Quiet[
  tsmARIMA = TimeSeriesModelFit[freezingPath, "ARIMA"]; (* works fine *)
  tsmARMA = TimeSeriesModelFit[freezingPath, "ARMA"] (* works fine *)
]; 

TimeSeriesForecast[tsmARIMA, 1] (* works fine *)

TimeSeriesForecast[tsmARMA, 1] (* freezes *)
```

What is going wrong here? What can I do to avoid or prevent such freezing?

[Addendum / partial solution from a day later -- passing the Path from the problematic TimeSeries solves the problem *sometimes*. Thus,

```
tsmARMA = TimeSeriesModelFit[freezingPath["Path"], "ARMA"];
TimeSeriesForecast[tsmARMA, 1] (* works fine *)
```

But there are other TimeSeries for which this approach does not help. Feels like there's a bug in Mathematica here.]

Comment: Which Mathematica version are you using? On what OS? I do not get any freezing with 10.4.1 on my MacBook Pro -- see [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zhAPvK0.png).

Comment: @AntonAntonov 10.4.1 on Windows 7. Frustrating, it's totally replicable on my machine (for ARMA only though, I've put thousands of TimeSeries through ARIMA without incident). Thanks for checking.

Comment: Does it freeze if you (1) work with the differences instead, (2) take, say, a 2/3 smaller signal sample, (3) subtract the mean curve? (etc...)

Comment: @AntonAntonov  Observations this morning -- 1. If I pass the timeseries data as a TimeSeries to TimeSeriesModelFit, Mathematica freezes when I run TimeSeriesForecast. However, if I pass only the Path data from the TimeSeries, there is no problem.  2. Scaling the datapoints, subtracting the mean, etc, has no difference. Changing the endpoints sometimes does.

Comment: I guess using the paths only (instead of TimeSeries) is the way to go...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Turns out that this approach does not always help. I have found cases that kill TimeSeriesForecast for both ARMA and ARIMA even using the "Path" trick. Sigh.

Comment: Would it be an option to use RLink` and, say, the libraries 'ts' or 'zoo'?

Comment: @AntonAntonov At this point I'd try anything. I'm no kind of guru at R though. Can you point me to a tutorial on how to assign a timeseries to a variable in R and generate a short-term prediction with a specified model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use RLink` and some of R's time series libraries like 'ts' or ['zoo'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf). A very comprehensive overview is given here: ["CRAN Task View: Time Series Analysis"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

### Using RLink`

It is a good idea to have access to R's libraries in your machine.

See Szabolcs Horvat's ["Setting up RLink for Mathematica"](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/setting-up-rlink-for-mathematica.html) .

Then follow examples, say, from here: [Quick-R: Time Series](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/timeseries.html).

#### Concrete code

The following code works and produces ARIMA and ARMA forecasts. The libraries have to be installed beforehand (or use `install.packages` instead of `library`.)

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/szhorvat/RLinkX/master/RLinkX.m"]

Needs["RLinkX`"]
InstallRX[]

(* SetEnvironment[
 "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" -> 
  "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib"] *)

InstallR["RHomeLocation" -> 
  "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources", "RVersion" -> 3]

RSet["freezingPath", N@freezingPath];

RSet["freezingPathVals", N@freezingPath[[All, 2]]];

RSet["freezingPathTimes", N@freezingPath[[All, 1]]];

REvaluate["library(zoo)"]

(* {"zoo", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", \
"reshape2", "plyr", "methods", "base"} *)

REvaluate["library(forecast)"]

(* {"forecast", "timeDate", "zoo", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", "reshape2", "plyr", "methods", "base"} *)

REvaluate["zooPath<-zoo(freezingPathVals,order.by=freezingPathTimes)"];

REvaluate["summary(time(zooPath))"]

(* RObject[{3.296*10^9, 3.306*10^9, 3.316*10^9, 3.316*10^9, 3.325*10^9, 3.335*10^9}, 
 RAttributes[
  "names" :> {"Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max."},
   "class" :> {"summaryDefault", "table"}]] *)

REvaluate["frPathTS<-ts(freezingPathVals)"];

REvaluate["fit<-arima(frPathTS,order=c(1,0,1))"];

REvaluate["fit<-HoltWinters(frPathTS,beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)"];

REvaluate["forecast(fit, 5)"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a simpler version of this working but I will study your example and improve my implementation.

Comment: @MichaelStern Great!